# How can I invoke an AJAX response?

Tags: 8, ajax

I have a Drupal 8 form I want to show via JavaScript code to make it appear as a popup across multiple pages. The form is rendered through an AJAX response in a controller. I can see the response using `$.ajax()`. How can I invoke the AJAX response to display on the page?

The JavaScript code is the following one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/aao_additions/modal_form',
    // Data parameter is the ajax response data for the intersitial popup.
    success: function(data, status, jqxhr) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(status);
      var popup = Drupal.ajax({
        url: "",
        base: false,
        element: false,
        progress: false,
      });
      // Simulate an AJAX response having arrived, and let the Ajax system handle it.
      popup.success(data, "success");
    },
    // Error function for if the modal form cannot be loaded.
    error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
      console.log(xhr);
      console.log("Desc: " + desc + "\nErr:" + err);
    },
  });
});
```

I receive an error on `Drupal.ajax`. I think it is preventing the response  rendering.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please update your question to include a properly documented code snippet of what you've done so far.

Comment: I've added my javascript where I'm trying to invoke the ajax. I'm sort of tricking the ajax call to run with a success call on Drupal.ajax(). This worked for my route path for the form but it throws an error on other pages.

Comment: At a very high level, I think you want a link that has a class of "use-ajax" on it whos callback hits your controller, the controller returns an AjaxResponse to trigger the modal. I don't understand your JS above, because that code will fire AJAX every single page. At the same time, The JS will need to conform to be a Drupal behavior so it is compatible. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Comment: I do have a link that calls my controller and this is the only page where the JavaScript call works. I want to call the controller automatically on other pages through my JavaScript. Is there a way to do this?